# AEM 6.0 vanity URLs under /content/dam unavailable after restart

Tags: aem, sling

I'm manually creating vanity URLs on assets by setting the sling:vanityPath
 parameter under the asset's content node.  This works fine for pages, and initially is working great for assets, but after rebooting the assets are no longer available under the vanity URLs and return a 404.  Is there some other place I need to configure them?

Comment: Can you test the link via the sling resource resolver test page? If that's not working then it might be a problem with some mappings. Also, are you using a dispatcher?

Comment: Is the property still present on the same nodes after the reboot? Maybe the assets somehow get updated and overwrite the `sling:vanityPath` properties?

Comment: @Ben Newman What do you mean by "**assets no longer available**"?  After reboot the vanity url properties got deleted or the asset nodes which are pointed by vanity urls got deleted?

Comment: The sling:vanityPath values are still there, the just aren't being picked up.  Looking at the sling resource resolver test page we can see them there when we first create them, but after reboot they're no longer there.  It looks like when the resource mapping is first initialized it's skipping either /content/dam or dam:Assets, but I can't see any tweak in the configuration that would change that.